# Jackson: customization escaping of double quotes while serialize an object to json

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson

By default jackson escape double quotes by backslash: \". 
So the json object looks like

```
{"title": "Testing \"double quotes\""}
```

I want to escape double quotes by two backslashes: \\". Like this

```
{"title": "Testing \\"double quotes\\""}
```

How to customize jackson serialization strategy for double quotes?

Comment: Don't use a JSON serializer like Jackson if you want to produce something that is not valid JSON.

Comment: I handle this json later. But in this step I have to make incorrect one.

Comment: This is a classic [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This will produce invalid JSON, so Jackson isn't going to help you do that. Assuming that you have no reverse solidus in the member names, you can just do it after outputting the actual string value:

```
String invalid = mapper.writeValueAsString(object).replace("\\", "\\\\");
```

Comment: So, isn't there any way to configure jackson to produce json like I want?

Comment: I don't think you will be able to. As I said, the JSON you want to produce is invalid. The quotation mark inside of the string is not escaped since you have escaped the '\' instead, so the next character in valid json should be '}', ']', or ',' but you will have 'd'. Why do you want the double '\' anyways?

Comment: Thank you for your answers, Aaryn.
I was trying to make double '\' because of a template engine I use. There is a custom writer escapes all '"' while it renders a model to a template. So, '\"' becomes '\\"' which is incorrect.
I fix my problem by customization of the writer.